# How to change menu link color when it is clicked

Tags: php, html, css

Iam trying to change the background color of the link visited,

here is my header code

```
echo ('<ul>');
echo('<li><a href="'.$FromPage.'">Back</a></li>');  
echo('<li><a href="Talent_Hire.php">Hire</a></li>');    
echo('<li><a href="Talent_Hire.php">Hire</a></li>');
echo('<li><a href="Talent_Hire.php">Hire</a></li>');
echo('<li><a href="Talent_Hire.php">Hire</a></li>');
echo('</ul>');
```

i know we can try with javascript but not getting exctly how...
please help me to fix this....

Comment: with that many echo's I'd opt for an array + foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS stated, this is a job for CSS + oh man, you code is wrong. Try something like this instead:

```
$string = '<ul>
             <li><a href="' . $FromPage . '">Back</a></li>
             <li><a href="Talent_Hire.php">Hire</a></li>
             <li><a href="Talent_Hire.php">Hire</a></li>
             <li><a href="Talent_Hire.php">Hire</a></li>
             <li><a href="Talent_Hire.php">Hire</a></li>
          </ul>';

echo $string;
```

And in you CSS file:

```
/** This will work only for tags `a` inside a `li` that is inside an `ul` tag.
    For all `a` tags, just remove the `ul` `li` part **/
ul li a:visited { background-color: #ff0000; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something you do with CSS ( A:visited class) as you do not know if user visited this link or not. His browser **might** know. See this tutorial: http://www.echoecho.com/csslinks.htm for more information

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
echo('<style>');
echo('a:visited{');  
echo('color:red;');   
echo('}');  
echo('</style>');
```

Or if you get tired of using so many `echo`s unnecessarily, you could just use:

```
echo '<style>
      a:visited{
          color:red;
      }
      </style>';
```

Comment: I'd do more echo()... :)

Comment: echo '<'; echo 's'; you get the picture

Comment: the echo is a proof og quality